# jScrollPane - Vertical scrollbar does not 'grow' with content

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari, cross-browser, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane (great stuff!) for scrollbars in my portfolio website, but i'm running in to a problem that i can't seem to solve myself.

The problem is highlighted when i change the width and length of the div with jQuery.

I have a column(div#projects) with the width of 180px. Inside that div there's a list of links. When a user clicks a link the div needs to 'grow' to 480px  width. Also the content of the div change. The list of links disappears and a list of projects is shown. That piece works. But jScrollPane won't grow with the content as i want it to do. I've got 2 different problems with that.

Safari:
In Safari the vertical scrollbar grow's automatically with the content. So that works fine. But when the width of the div grows to 400px, suddenly there appears a horizontal scrollbar with the width of 180px(the previous width of the div). .

Firefox:
The biggest problem is in Firefox however. There, the vertical scrollbar won't automatically grow with the content. I tried using autoReinitialise, that works fine for the vertical scrollbar to grow with the content, but delivers me another problem. When i use autoReinitialise, the div who just grew to 480px, goes back to 180px again. So autoReinitialise does not solve my problem.

In Firefox you can also see that one div doesn't look the way it should (if you have clicked a link and see the projects). That's around the height of the previous content (the list with links).

That's my biggest problem. But i also have another small question: is it possible to always show the scrollbars OR give unique classes to every div.scroll-pane? 
Cause when i adjust the width of div#projects to 480px, i also have to change the width of the scroll-pane container. Now, i use jQuery to give every div a unique class. And if the scrollbars are not always visible, there are not always the same amount of divs. So now i always show the scrollbars by putting another div under the content. But if i can give every scroll-pane div a unique class (manually) i don't need to always show the scrollbars.

The website where this is al about: http://nieuw.yworks.nl. Partically the "projects" div. Click a link in that div and you'll see the problems. (Safari and partically Firefox).

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I'm now struggling for 2 days already.

Thanks in advance (and hope my English is not that bad:))

Edit: I use Safari 5.4.1 and Firefox 9.0.1. Did not test it in Internet Explorer, that will also cause a lot more problems i guess.

---

I think i found the problem. These divs (pic: http://nieuw.yworks.nl/extern/divs.png) are still 180px instead of 480px. Only thing is, i don't now why. This is the code:

$(".item-30").css("width", "480px");
                    $(".item-31").css("width", "420px");

```
                $("#projects").stop().animate({width:'480px'},{queue:false, duration:300});

                $("#projects").css("background","#fff");

                $('#projectsList').hide();
                $('#projectsContent').show();
                $("#contact").stop().animate({left:'1524px'},{queue:false, duration:300});
                $("#footer").stop().animate({left:'1745px'},{queue:false, duration:300});

                var api = $('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
                api.destroy();
                $('#projects').jScrollPane({contentWidth:480}).data('jsp');
```

And in Firefox i don't use animate cause that didn't seem to work, i just use $("#projects").css("width", "480px");

This is the same problem as i mentioned in the second part of my question. The .jspContainer and .jspPane divs don't have unique id's. And i can't give them cause jScrollPane generates them. And if i adjust .jspContainer and .jspPane than thats for al those divs. And if i adjust the width of them via jQuery it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var api = $('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
 api.destroy();  
 $("#projects").stop().animate({width:'480px'},300, function(){
                         $('#projects').jScrollPane({contentWidth:480}).data('jsp');
                    });
```

Clarification:

1) Animate works absolutely fine on Firefox

2) You should never have to directly change the size of jspContainer or jspPane the sizes of these are set by jscrollpane when it is initialised e.g. by calling :

```
$('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
```

3) If you are only changing the content of the scrollpane you just need to reinitialise it so that it can recalculate the scrollbars and contentpane by doing something like this:

```
var api = $('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
api.reinitialise();
```

4)If you are actually changing the size of the div you are apllying jscrollpane to you will have to destroy the instance of jscrollpane and recreate it. I have found that if changing the width it is safest to specify the width explicitly when doing this, like so:

```
var api = $('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
api.destroy();
$('#projects').width(480); 
$('#projects').jScrollPane({contentWidth:480}).data('jsp');
```

5)if you are animating the width, you need to wait until the animation has finished before you can reinitialise the scrollpane so you initialise the scrollpane in the callback function of the animation like so:

```
     var api = $('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
     api.destroy();
     $("#projects").animate({width:'480px'},300, function(){
                         $('#projects').jScrollPane({contentWidth:480}).data('jsp');
                    });
```

6)When I was trying to do similar effect. I wanted to initiate a series of animations one after the after. You can do this by nesting each animation inside the callback of the last for example:

```
$("#projects .content").animate({opacity:0},300, function(){ //anim branch 1
           //content fade animation finished now do this:
           var api = $('#projects').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
           api.destroy();
           $("#projects").animate({width:'480px'},300, function(){
                          // width change animation finished now do this:
                          $('#projects').jScrollPane({contentWidth:480}).data('jsp');
                          //fade content back in
                          $("#projects .content").animate({opacity:1},300);
           });
});
$("#contacts").animate({left:1000},300); //anim branch 2
```

7) If you use $('.element').hide() this will set the element to display:none; and take it out of the page, this means that if you set the content of a dic to display none and try to apply a jscrollpane to it, the size will be calculated incorrectly. It works if you animate the opacity instead but obviously will not work in browsers which do not support opacity.

8) Finally, In example six there are two animation branches, these will run simultaneously.

Comment: I just tested your code (first destroying it). That seems to work, vertically. But now my div doesn't grow to 480px. Well, my div seems to grow, but the scroll pane container doesn't. Cause, the 'contact' div is being pushed away by the 'projects' div, and the 'projects' div gets an horizontal scrollbar, but the content issn't visible. Do you have any clue? Cause i only added your code right after i change the width of the div... I adjust it live so you can see the problem at the site.

Comment: add your code- you can tell jscroll specifically not to horizontal scroll but I dont think this is the issue. It is probably due to when you are destroying/creating the scrollpane. If you are resizing the div with an animation you should recreate the scollpane in the function callback of the animation.

Comment: I added my reaction to your latest post in my first post :-) Couldn't post it here, was to large.

Comment: see updated answer - you need to reinitialise the scrollpane after the animation is complete so do it within the callback function

Comment: I'm not that familiar with jQuery/JavaScript. Can you tell me what's the right notation of my code? I posted the code in my first post. And how should i do the same without the animation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I have updated my answer to try to clarify some things for you. Also, I noticed you were animating the left position of the divs to move them. why not set them to display:inline-block and float left so that you no longer have to do this.

Comment: I used your piece of code at step 6. But that lets al the content disappear, the div gets to 480px and immediately goes back to 180px. The code at step 5 comes close. With that code the vertical scroll works fine after the projects get visible. But the width of #projects goes to 480px and immediately goes back to 180px. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it's getting kind of frustrating.

Comment: Sorry my man, my bad. You should be destroying the api before changing the width See revised examples in my answer. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I removed al unnecessary code and used your latest code. It seems to work, except for some small things. The div 'grows' fine, but vertically there is no scrollbar for the length of the content with projects. I couldn't use opacity cause the content will appear under the list that was there. So i used show/hide();. Also when you resize your browser in height(smaller) the div goes back to original width. Further, everything seems to work well. Can you help with these last 2 problems? It starts to look like something :-D

Comment: As I said you cannot use show/hide, it doeasnt work, I got round this by bringing the content in with an ajax call. As far as the browser resize is concerned, you have to code in for this, it can get quite complicated. The standard script (provided on jscroll site) has no width set so it will revert to the original width). I wrote a seperate script to handle window resize which does the same as above examples, destroying api, get new width then reinitialise. I suggest you have a crack at this and come back with a new question if you have problems. Feel free to message me if you need help.

Comment: If you want you can check out the code on the site I am building at the moment at www.imgshack.co.uk, if you look at page_script.js through firebug you will find the resize function inside the document ready function, this uses the sizer function at the top of the page(this calculates sizes for all resizes)... as i said it can get quite complex but it might get you started.... good luck

Comment: I say you cant use show/hide, you can as long as you show the content then initialise the scrollpane in the callback of the show.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you apply `jscrollpane()` after the window loads. That is use `windows.load`, rather than using `document.ready`.